# How do I get MPU 6050 gyroscope data using "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h" library

Tags: arduino, imu, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm currently calibrating the MPU6050 chip using an arduino mega 2560. I am using the J Rowberg 12c dev libraries. I can get it to print raw accelerometer and gyroscpe values (very unstable, wildly changing values). In the digital motion processing chip library, I can get it to print euler angles, quaternions, real world acceleration and actual acceleration but there is no option to get gyroscope data.

can I use the DMP library to get gyro data or is it only possible to get raw unprocessed gyro values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the header files of the 12cdev lib and I figured it out.

you have to first add the line VectorInt16 gyro; to your motion variables, then you add the line

mpu.dmpGetGyro(&gyro, fifoBuffer);

to your outputs.

Comment: Any chance you could add a link to the libraries?

Comment: The library is no longer supported but you can grab it here. It is prone to crashing though so you need to do some troubleshooting with the library.              https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050

Comment: Thanks for the reply! OK I'll take a look at it and see what I can learn.